# static in different languages

Tags: programming-languages, static, keyword

I've heard there are differences between languages about the meaning of the keyword **`static`**, but I've not found a good list that consolidates those differences.

Here's what I know about the meaning of **`static`** in C++:

- For local static variables within a function, the variable is initialized at startup and the value is saved across function calls.
- Static data members are shared among all instances of a class.  In other words, there is only one instance of a static data member.  Static data members must be initialized at file scope.
- Static member functions have access only to static members.
- In recursive code, a static object or variable is guaranteed to have the same state in different instances of a block of code.
- Static objects and variables defined at file scope only have internal linkage.  No other files may use them.

How does the meaning of **`static`** change in other languages?

Comment: Static locals in C++ are initialized on first invocation, not on startup.

Comment: @Iraimbilanja, can you give me a reference for that?  MSDN seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Iraimbilanja: C&V 6.7 (see my post below for the exact line).

Comment: scottie: well... struct A { A() { cout << "f"; } }; void f() { static A a; } int main() { cout<<"m"; f(); } //prints mf

Comment: Sure, that just means the output is executed in order.  That doesn't prove the struct isn't initialized at start-up.  Honestly, I'm not invested in either answer, I'd just liked to know the right one.

Comment: Define "initialized" then. Unless you mean "having its bytes filled with zeros", it's pretty obvious that the object here is initialized on first invocation.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, memory is made available and its value is set to zero.

Comment: Right. In that case it's done on startup. However, you should know that in C++, we call an object "initialized" only when its constructor has ran - i.e., when it is in a valid state for use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**C**

---

- The keyword can change either the linkage or the duration (lifetime) of an object.
- Variables are always initialized to 0
- Functions have internal linkage.
- If declared in file level scope: variables have internal linkage and static duration (i.e. exists throughout the lifetime of the program)
- If declared in block scope: variables have no linkage but static duration
- There can multiple declarations of the same static variable in a translation unit. However, note that they must be the same. E.g: at file-level scope:

---

```
int a;        // a has external linkage

static int a; // a now has static linkage
              // same as if you wrote: static int a = 0;

//...

static int b; // static linkage

extern int b; // extern loses its meaning, b still has internal linkage

//...

extern int b; // b has external linkage

static int b; // error

//...

void func() {
  static int x; // automatic linkage, static duration
                // same as if you wrote: static int x = 0;
}
```

**C++**

---

- At file level scope the usage has been deprecated for both variables and members in favor of anonymous namespaces. Exists only as compatibility
- Variables still get default initialized (as in C) to 0
- **"6.7 The zero-initialization (8.5) of all local objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is performed before any other initialization takes place [...] "**
- Variables have static storage duration unless accompanied by a `thread_local` specifier (from C++0x onwards)
- There can be only one definition of a static in a translation unit
- Member variables/functions mean they are properties of the class and not the instances
  Legal access syntax: instance.property or Class::property
- Static member functions can only access only static member variables 
  No `this` pointer for such functions
- Non-static members can however access any static member
- At file level objects have internal linkage except for class members which have a class scope
- Class members need to be defined either in the class declaration or outside explicitly via class name and scope resolution operator
- Cannot use `this` in a static method

---

**ActionScript**

---

- Class methods as in C++
- cannot use `this` or `super` in a static method
- Accessed only through class name and not instance name
- Not inherited
- Derived classes however have access to bases' static properties
- Variables that are declared with both the static and const keywords must be initialized at the same time as you declare the constant

---

**Object Oriented Design**

---

- The Singleton design pattern is considered by many as a glorified static object
- Used in Factory design pattern

---

I may have missed a lot of other things -- feel free to chip in.

Comment: Chipping in years later: C++ file scope static deprecation is no more.

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi the static keyword is used exclusively for defining class methods. In Delphi a *normal* class method can be declared virtual and overridden in a subclass. Additionally Delphi has a *self* variable, similar to the *this* pointer in other languages. However in a class method the *self* points to the class in which the method is called instead of an instance.

Declaring a class method *static* means:

1. It cannot be overridden in a subclass
2. It does not have a *self* pointer

This means a static class method can only access class members in the class it was defined in, while a normal class method can access overridden class members in derived classes.

There are other informal uses of static in the Delphi documentation usually referring to a feature unchangability (is that a word?). For instance a static array vs a dynamic array. All instance methods in Delphi are static unless declared otherwise.

Comment: Also worth noting mandatory `static` for class functions in records in newer Delphi version.

Answer (score 2):

In C# it pretty much always means: "related to a type rather than an instance of the type".

Comment: @R Bemrose - well nearly. "static import" doesn't feel quite the same; it's certainly not the "type equivalent" of a non-static import, for example.

Comment: But extension methods, which are always "related to an instance of a type", can only be declared in static classes... breaking the nice rule-of-thumb.

Comment: Well, sort of - and sort of not. The instance is provided as an argument in that case. The point is that there's no *inherent* context.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET, a `Static` variable is just like a C++ local static variable.

However, there is no class-wide `Static`; use `Shared` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In C# there are 3 ways a static keyword can be used:

- On class definition, which means the class will only expose static members and cannot be instanciated
- On a class member, which means that the member can be called without having to instanciate the class.
- On a constructor, which means that the static constructor will allways be called before a static member is called. (Those are mostly performance bottlenecks and therefore not recommended)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget that on class definition it also means the class can declare extension methods. Also, "can be called without having to instanciate the class" is a very unorthodox way of describing it. And on a constructor, isn't the important thing that it becomes a "class constructor" instead?

Comment: If you have a class with 3 static members and one static contructor, the static contructor is always called before execution of the static member, every time a member is called. This is different from a class contructor, because a class contructor is called only when the class is instanciated.

Answer (score 1):

Python has the decorator @staticmethod, which when applied to a class member, makes the method available on the class rather than instances, and passes no automatic arguments to the method.  The @classmethod decorator performs a similar function, but passes the class as the first argument, making it much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

In C, static flags a function or global variable as local to the file its located in.

It's kinda like private in other languages. Sorta.

If it's in a function, then static preallocates that variable in the data section of the binary, rather than on the stack at run time.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET static is used procedure level to mean the variable is associated with all executions of the procedure (it's preserved from call to call).  That's a bit of an arcane usage in an Object-Oriented application though.

The counterpart is "Shared" which means the method or member is type level (you don't need an instance to access it).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia summarizes many different meanings of `static`:

[Static Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_method#Static_methods), [static variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable#Static_Variables_as_Class_Variables), [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_checking).