# Switch case on an enum that is never changed

Tags: c, switch-statement

I came across the following code and can't seem to understand what's going on here.
The enum `pattern` is never changed so why do a `switch` on it?

```
enum pattern { PAT_ZERO, PAT_SEQ, PAT_PIPE };
static enum pattern pattern;

static ssize_t fill_in_buf(struct thread *ignore, void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
    size_t i;
    __u8 *p;

    (void)ignore;

    switch (pattern) {
    case PAT_ZERO:
        printf("fill_in_buf PAT_ZERO\n");
        memset(buf, 0, nbytes);
        break;

    case PAT_SEQ:
        printf("fill_in_buf PAT_SEQ\n");
        for (p = buf, i = 0; i < nbytes; ++i, ++p)
            *p = i % 63;
        break;

    case PAT_PIPE:
        printf("fill_in_buf PAT_PIPE\n");
        return fread(buf, 1, nbytes, stdin);
    }

    return nbytes;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The code is from http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/usb/ffs-test.c#L362

Comment: Is `pattern` changed by some other function?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Why would it be? enum pattern != pattern

Comment: @tzippy: Because some code somewhere else changes the value of `pattern`?

Comment: @self. I didn't try it... may be correct.. can you explain a bit more

Comment: `pattern` must be in use in the code not shown here .

Comment: @Dayalrai It is static, I don't see how. THe code must be a test( name:ffs-test.c) therefore it is there to check the values and is changed by hand if needed.

Comment: @tzippy No I saw you link I will learn about it. Thanks! ..I should remove the comment..

Comment: @self. That is `static global`. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @self. That's actually the only possibility that makes sense, yes.

Comment: @Dayalrai You're wrong, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4576643/2327831

Answer (score 0):

It looks like test/debugging code, the programmer wanted a few varieties to choose from.

It's quite unexpectedly written, typically you'd see this done with the preprocessor and `#if defined` to choose one code path.

The two first lines could be clarified to:

```
static const enum { PAT_ZERO, PAT_SEQ, PAT_PIPE } pattern = PAT_ZERO;
```

Since there's no point in introducing a name for the enum, or making the variable non-`const`.