# C: static struct

Tags: c, struct

I am fairly new to C and am going over some code to learn about hashing.

I came across a file that contained the following lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int64_t timing(bool start)
{
    static      struct timeval startw, endw; // What is this?
    int64_t     usecs   = 0;

    if(start) {
        gettimeofday(&startw, NULL);
    }
    else {
        gettimeofday(&endw, NULL);
        usecs   =
               (endw.tv_sec - startw.tv_sec)*1000000 +
               (endw.tv_usec - startw.tv_usec);
    }
    return usecs;
}
```

I have never come across a static struct defined in this manner before. Usually a struct is preceded by the definition/declaration of the struct. However, this just seems to state there are going to be static struct variables of type timeval, startw, endw.

I have tried to read up on what this does but have not yet found a good enough explanation. Any help?

Comment: A static struct is no different from a static int. Do you know how static local variables work?

Comment: I think it's because fuction timing is called a lot , so define it to be static,which is defined only one time.

Comment: @Jon: yes I do I read this article [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576607/static-keyword-in-ansi-c). Like I said I am new and searching online did not yield a very good explanation hence I opened this question to all who can and is willing to help me.

Comment: @michaeltang Not really (allocating on stack doesn't add much). `timing` is *stateful* function, on `timing(false)` it returns time difference from last `timing(true)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct timeval` is a struct declared somewhere in `sys/time.h`. That line you highlighted declares two static variables named `startw` and `endw` of type `struct timeval`. The `static` keyword applies to the variables declared, not the struct (type).

You're probably more used to structs having a `typedef`'d name, but that's not necessary. If you declare a struct like this:

```
struct foo { int bar; };
```

Then you've declared (and defined here) a type called `struct foo`. You'll need to use `struct foo` whenever you want to declare a variable (or parameter) of that type. Or use a typedef to give it another name.

```
foo some_var;              // Error: there is no type named "foo"
struct foo some_other_var; // Ok
typedef struct foo myfoo;
myfoo something_else;      // Ok, typedef'd name
// Or...
typedef struct foo foo;
foo now_this_is_ok_but_confusing;
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped me understand it more. I was thinking that timeval must be a struct defined in a header file somewhere but I was not sure how to check? I tried man timeval in the terminal but that yielded nothing (I guess this is because it is a struct). Do you have any tips on how I can check in the future if a struct is declared in a header file somewhere in the standard C library?

Comment: The man page for the function that requires (or returns) that type will list the headers it needs. So it'll be one of them. You understand that this is plain C syntax for using a `struct` though, right? There's nothing special about `struct timeval` in particular or the fact that it's defined in a system header.

Comment: I see. I thought there was a trick or something that you did that made you immediately know that it is defined in that header file. But it seems you just know from experience......I wish I can reach that level soon. Thanks for the thorough answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here the important **point** is the static local variable. **Static local variable** will be initialized **only** one time, and the value will be **saved** and shared in the hole program context. This means the *startw* and *endw* will be used on next *timing* invoked.

In the program, you can invoke the *timing* many times:

```
timing(true);
//startw will be initialzed
timing(false);
//endw is initialized, and the startw has been saved on the prevous invoking.
......
```

I hope my description is clear. You can see the **static local variable** is *static variable* will be saved in global context.