# Calculating sum of prime number below 2 million by using Sieve of Atkin

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-atkin

I'm doing project Euler and I got this problem. I run the code in VS 2013 and the program crashes because of overflow.

This is my method:

```
void problem10()
{
    long long int iter = 2, sum = 0;

    //Sieve of Atkin
    bool isPrime[PRIME_LIMIT+1];

    for (long long int i = 5; i <= PRIME_LIMIT; i++)
    {
        isPrime[i] = false;
    }

    long long int lim = ceil(sqrt(PRIME_LIMIT));

    for (long long int x = 1; x <= lim; x++)
    {
        for (long long int y = 1; y <= lim; y++)
        {
            long long int n = 4 * x*x + y*y;
            if (n <= PRIME_LIMIT && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5))
            {
                isPrime[n] = true;
            }

            n = 3 * x*x + y*y;
            if (n <= PRIME_LIMIT && (n % 12 == 7))
            {
                isPrime[n] = true;
            }

            n = 3 * x*x - y*y;
            if (x > y && n < PRIME_LIMIT && n % 12 == 11)
            {
                isPrime[n] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // eliminate composites by seiving
    for (long long int n = 5; n <= lim; n++)
    {
        if (isPrime[n])
        {
            for (long long int k = n*n; k <= PRIME_LIMIT; k+= k*k)
            {
                isPrime[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (long long int n = 5; n <= PRIME_LIMIT; n++)
    {
        if (isPrime[n])
        {
            sum += n;
        }
    }
    sum = sum + 2 + 3;
    printf("%lld\n", sum);
    /* //A basic approach -- too slow
    while (iter < PRIME_LIMIT)
    {
        bool isDivisible = false;
        int prime = iter;
        for (int a = 2; a < iter; a++)
        {
            if (prime%a == 0)
            {
                isDivisible = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isDivisible){}
        else
        {
            //printf("prime is: %d\n", prime);
            sum += prime;
        }
        iter++;
    }
    printf("Sum of prime is: %d\n", sum);
    */
}
```

This method includes 2 approaches to calculate the sum of all prime numbers in ranges `PRIME_LIMIT`. The second approach take too long to get the result, and probably take whole day. The first approach is using sieve of Atkin, the program crashes!

Is there any mistake in my code?? Please help!

Comment: "program crashes because of overflow." ?

Comment: What is `PRIME_LIMIT`? If it's `2000000`, then you are overflowing the stack and you should allocate that array on the heap, or allocate it statically.

Comment: I think it is. Sorry I'm a beginner in C, I'm more familiar with Java. I say this because almost my programs crash because of that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's talk about this problem:

### Integer Sizes

Much like Java, Integers in C have a limit to the size that they can fit. Here, you chose to use a `long long int`. Luckily for this problem, the sum will fit in that data type. For other Project Euler problems, you will need to use a BigInt class.

### Your Slow Approach

The slow approach is actually fine if you add one addition. We know, that the list of divisors that we need to search, is actually less than all of the numbers from `2 ... n`. So we can change one of your loops to this:

```
int max = ciel(sqrt(iter));
for (int a = 2; a < max; a++)
    if (prime % a == 0)
        isDivisible = true;
        break;
```

If we do that, your code will finish relatively quickly.

### Your Fast Approach

I haven't fully gone through this code, because it doesn't look like the sieve of eratosthenes that I remember, but at the very least, you are going to overflow the stack with your allocations.

```
#define PRIME_LIMIT 2000000
bool isPrime[PRIME_LIMIT+1];
```

Let's fix that:

```
#define PRIME_LIMIT 2000000
static bool isPrime[PRIME_LIMIT+1]
```

Or:

```
#define PRIME_LIMIT 2000000
bool *isPrime = calloc(PRIME_LIMIT + 1, sizeof(bool));
```

### Recommendations

I'd really recommend to not start by trying to implement the Sieve of Atkin. If I was to implement this as a learning exercise, I'd do it in this order:

1. The slow approach that you've done above. In python, similar code takes about 1 minute to solve the problem. I'd suspect C could do it in about 10 seconds (or faster).
2. The [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a much simpler sieve to implement. I'd recommend using that next.
3. Then try to implement the [sieve of atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin). An algorithm of that speed is completely unnecessary for a problem of this size though.

Comment: According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576607/static-keyword-in-ansi-c     I dont really understand why you put the keyword static in front of array declaration. Due to the post, the static keyword doesn't do anything about memory allocation. So why you put it there? Please explain this for me!!

Comment: Without the static, the block is allocated on the stack. With the static, the block is likely allocated in the bss or the data segment of the program. The stack has a limited size, that 2000000 bytes will likely overflow. The bss segment, the data segment and the heap, are much larger.

Comment: oh OK! I understand that! But when I try to change the array declaration to static or using function calloc, it prints out some nice numbers which are 3804, 45, etc. I think these are random numbers ...

Comment: @TrungBún: I don't understand what the sieve of atkin does, nor if your implementation matches the algorithm, so I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: That's fine! No problem! Thank you for you time! I will try to figure out by myself! But I'm sure that I follow exactly the psuedo code on wikipedia :)

Comment: @TrungBún the pseudocode on WP is bogus and it says so in the talk page of that article. Try using Eratosthenes and compare their speeds for several problem sizes.