# Find sum of prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c, algorithm, overflow

I' using Sieve to calculate the sum of all prime number below 2 million, but the program keeps crashing after trying several times due to overflow. It works fine with `PRIME_LIMIT = 200000`

So what is the problem in my code? I don't think that's the algorithm problem. When I put `static`  keyword when declaring the boolean array, it prints out the wrong sum ... without the keyword, it's overflow ...

This is the method I wrote:

```
void problem10()

    {
        unsigned long long int iter = 2, sum = 0;

        static bool prime[PRIME_LIMIT];

        for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < PRIME_LIMIT; i++)
        {
            prime[i] = true;
        }

        unsigned long long int limit = ceil(sqrt(PRIME_LIMIT));

        for (unsigned long long int i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
        {
            if (prime[i])
            {
                for (unsigned long long int j = i*i; j < PRIME_LIMIT; j += i)
                {
                    prime[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        for (unsigned long long int i = 2; i < PRIME_LIMIT; i++)
        {
            if (prime[i])
            {
                sum += i;
                //printf("Primes are: %d\n", i);
            }
        }
            printf("Sum of prime is: %llu\n", sum);
    }
```

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Comment: Without `static`, the `bool prime[PRIME_LIMIT]` array is probably too large to be allocated on the *heap*, this causes the crash. – With `static`, it should work and actually produces the correct result in my test.

Comment: The code works for me when I include enough headers (`<math.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stdio.h>`) and provide a `main()` that calls the function (and remove unused variable `iter`).  The result is `Sum of prime is: 142913828922` when compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit on Mac OS X 10.9.2 with GCC 4.8.2.
`

Comment: Correction: The array is too large to be allocated on the *stack*. But that was already explained in the answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969072/calculating-sum-of-prime-number-below-2-million-by-using-sieve-of-atkin.

Comment: "wrong sum" — what does it print? What do you expect it to print? How do you know it's wrong?

Comment: For PRIME_LIMIT = 200000 I get 1709600813 when compiled for 32-bit on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012, with and without `static` before `bool prime`. @JonathanLeffler: strange I get not the same result as you.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: 1709600813 is the sum of all primes up to 200.000, 142913828922 is the sum of the primes up to 2.000.000.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I was testing PRIME_LIMIT of 2000000 (two million), not 200000 (two hundred thousand).

Comment: Oops, now we have revealed the solution of a [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/about) problem :-)

Comment: well when i run the code, it give a different result for each time i run ...

Comment: the math.h header solve problem! But can I ask you why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said in a comment, you did not include `<math.h>`. Then the compiler does not know
the declarations of the `sqrt()` and `ceil()` functions:

```
double sqrt(double x);
double ceil(double x);
```

and you probably got warnings about "implicitly declared functions".

The compiler then assumes that these functions return an `int` and will therefore generate
wrong code which can cause any kind of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! I learnt C from a Java programmer's view. I'm using VS 2013 and I'm a bit curious that why the compiler (intelligent sense feature of VS) doesn't give me an error when I use a function from a library that wasn't included in the code?

Comment: No, it didn't give me that error. It just compile perfectly and give me random number each time

Comment: @TrungBún: It *is allowed* to call a function without declaring it first (for historic compatibility reasons). GCC and Clang give compiler *warnings* in that case. I do not have VS here, so I cannot explain why you don't get a warning.