# Finish a thread when condition is produced. C/C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I have a C code that checks if the left buttom of the mouse has been pressed. It works fine but I don't know how to unhook and exit the current thread after calling the final() function.

This is the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
static int count = 0;
static int finalNum;
if (count==0){
    //////Generate random number 
    srand(time(NULL)); // Seed the time
    finalNum = rand() % (150 - 50) + 50; // Generate the number, assign to variable.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
//int count = 0;
MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != NULL){
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            count++;
            printf("%d",count);
            if (count==finalNum){ // user clicked random times the mouse so we launch the final function
                printf("\ndone!\n");
                final();

            }
            printf("clicked");
        }
        printf("Mouse position X = %d  Mouse Position Y = %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI MyMouseLogger(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    // here I put WH_MOUSE instead of WH_MOUSE_LL
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, hInstance, NULL);
    MSG message;

    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}

void custom_delay(){

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;
    //////Generate random number to call a function after rand() number of clicks
    srand(time(NULL)); // Seed the time
    int finalNum = rand() % (150 - 50) + 50; // Generate the number, assign to variable.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    printf("%d", finalNum);
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyMouseLogger, (LPVOID)argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);
    if (hThread)
        return WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    else
        return 1;
    }
printf("Keep going");
}
```

I've tried with ExitThread(0); but it closes all the threads and not only the MyMouseLogger process to print "Keep going".

How should I do it?

thank you for your help!

Comment: When the `MyMouseLogger` thread exits, your main's call to wait on it will return, and main itself will return... program termination.  What else could you expect?  If you want to see "Keep going", get rid of the `return` before `WaitForSingleObject(...`.

Comment: You are probably lacking some *Windows* or *Win32* tag. This does not look like C++11 `std::thread` or Posix pthreads.

Comment: Try post a WM_QUIT message in the `final` function.

Comment: [OT]: You have to seed only once, and `rand` is not thread safe. You may use the new facilities of `<random>` from C++11 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really related to hooks as such; you are rather just asking how to safely stop a thread from running.

ExitThread() is never a good choice. So implement your own way to safely stop the thread. In this case, it can be done by for example creating an event through CreateEvent() before creating the thread. Then have your thread check for this event each time in the loop:

```
while (WaitForSingleObject(hevent_stopthread, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 &&)
       GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
```

where `hevent_stopthread` it the HANDLE to your custom event.

Then simply set this event from the final() function. Your main() function will wait until the thread has finished by its own, by returning 0. Once that happens, you can clean up the event with a call to CloseHandle().

Comment: You might want MsgWaitForMultipleObjects there, otherwise the thread can't exit while GetMessage is blocked.

Comment: Can you please tell me where do I have to put it into my code? Im still learning C. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use PostThreadMessage to send a WM_QUIT to the thread, which will cause its message loop to exit.

Comment: +1 This is actually a good idea for this specific case. For a more generic approach, see the answer I just posted.

Comment: Thank you for the response but, how do I get the `idThread` that I need to use as parameter in `PostThreadMessage`into the `mouseProc` function. I say that because the CreateThread function is in the main not in the `mouseProc` function

Comment: @user1618465 The quick solution is to make it a `static` file scope variable which mouseProc can then access. A more elegant solution is to put all thread handling in a separate file of its own and wrap it up in functions you can call from main(). Or if C++ is an option, make a class for it.