# Why static fields are called "static"?

Tags: java

What is the reason behind using the word "static" in "static variables" or "static methods"?

I'm **not** asking for the **definition** of "static", just asking why it is called so.

Comment: well if you know the definition of static, you would understand why they are called static variables and static methods...

Comment: because they dont change... they are **static**

Comment: @Scott, are you seriously suggesting that `static int x = 2;` can never change the value to 3?

Comment: no, but `static int x` will always be in the same place when you go to look for it.

Comment: Well, actually, so will the non-static during it's lifetime. Your `static int x` may be in a totally _different_ place next time it's instantiated (i.e., when you re-run the program). Static is really only whether or not something is class-specific or object-specific. Even under C, where the concept came from, static has nothing to do with location. _One_ of its meaning is static _value_ (not location) in terms of maintaining values between invocations of a function but all others are neither unchanging value nor location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a hold over from C++ and C before that. In the C context, one of its meanings was for variables that keep their value between invocations.  I presume that's where 'static' comes from - it doesn't reset the value (as opposed to a const where the value cannot change)

Comment: +1 - That's as close as we are likely to get.  The original reasons why `static` was chosen, and what other alternatives were considered are probably only known to the original Oak team ... if they can still remember from 20+ years ago.

Comment: Actually, static is overloaded in C. The definition you give is when you use it within a function where it controls duration. It's also used outside of functions to limit the visibility of something to the current translation unit. In C++, it has a third use within a class to create a variable shared amongst all instances. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943280/difference-between-static-in-c-and-static-in-c/943303#943303 but +1 for the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose the best way to think of it is that "static" means unchanging, and it is the *location* of the variable that is unchanging when when you switch between the different instances of a class. The main thing is to eradicate any thought from your mind that the *value* of a static variable is unchanging: it may even be changed by another instance of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

In Head First Java, there is a nice explanation of static. Static means stable not changing thats obvious from meaning and its quite obvious that it does not change.

Static mean sharing in Java. There is a nice picture where two child sharing one ice cream and showed static variable analogy. For more info please read Head First Java.

Answer (score -3):

> Definition of STATIC 1 : exerting
>   force by reason of weight alone
>   without motion 2 : of or relating to
>   bodies at rest or forces in
>   equilibrium 3 : showing little change
>    4 a :
>   characterized by a lack of movement,
>   animation, or progression b :
>   producing an effect of repose or
>   quiescence  5 a :
>   standing or fixed in one place :
>   stationary b of water : stored in a
>   tank but not under pressure

just apply the definition to a variable...

Comment: I can't tell if you're trying to be funny or not. _None_ of those definitions match static in Java

Comment: @Software, if you mean at one location, that's rubbish. _All_ variables are fixed during their lifetime, even non-static file level and automatic variables in C, as well as object variables in Java.

Comment: All static means in Java is that something belongs to the class rather than an object. I can't see _anything_ even remotely close to that in this answer. The definition seems to lean towards `const` rather than `static`.

Comment: obviously the variables are water stored in a tank but not under pressure. but seriously, i do think this question is a bit silly.

Comment: I asked this question because of a line in wikipedia : _"..In other words, data in a static or global variable is normally always located at the same memory location"_ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-Specific_Storage

Comment: in light of the additional information: that article is for unmanaged languages, really. Java abstracts most of that for you.