# How do you use a class method to distribute multiple shared instances of UIManagedDocument?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, static, ios5

I have a helper class that distributes a shared instance of UIManagedDocument.  The idea is that the user requests the UIManagedDocument shared instance for a particular file on disk.  In this case, it's a core data store.  If the user requests the core data store located at a different path I want to distribute an instance of UIManagedDocument for that file.

My question is: Is it ok to create a new instance of a UIManagedDocument and assign it to the static variable when the file changes?  For example:

```
+ (UIManagedDocument *)sharedManagedDocumentForFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    static UIManagedDocument *sharedDocument = nil;

    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    // url is "<Documents Directory>/<vacationName>"

    // Create the shared instance lazily upon the first request.
    if (sharedDocument == nil) {
        sharedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    }

    if (sharedDocument.fileURL != url) {
        UIManagedDocument *newDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
        sharedDocument = newDocument;
    }

    return sharedDocument;
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is distribute only one instance of a UIManagedDocument so in the event there are multiple writers to the core data store I don't have to constantly keep the changes in sync. However, since there are multiple core data stores on disk I can't just distribute the same static variable every time.

Any ideas? I'm absolutely stuck on even how to approach this design problem... Any help is appreciated.

Thanks - Jake

Comment: I believe this comes with a mandatory sentence.

Comment: @Jave V I think he was joking...lol

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'ok' and 'legal'?

Comment: By 'ok' I mean would I run into some bugs or issues by changing the memory address pointed to by the static variable.

Comment: This does not look like 'shared' document, but rather like 'currentDocument'. If so, deal with it appropriately: make a corresponding property somewhere higher in the hierarchy (application delegate for example), use the property respectively and get rid of the class method and the static variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do: no, this won't work.

I'm assuming you want to persist a `sharedDocument` for each unique file on disk requested, independently of any other `sharedDocuments` in existence. But your code won't do that, because every time a fileName is passed in which is different from the last passed in fileName, the reference to the old `UIManagedDocument` is lost.

Imagine the following (contrived) scenario:

```
UIManagedDocument *docA = [self sharedManagedDocumentForFile:@"fileA.txt"];
UIManagedDocument *docB = [self sharedManagedDocumentForFile:@"fileB.txt"];
UIManagedDocument *docA2 = [self sharedManagedDocumentForFile:@"fileA.txt"];
```

You're expecting `docA` and `docA2` to be the same `UIManageDocument` but that won't happen, because the middle line caused your static variable to forget the original managed document for `file1.txt1`.

I'd abandon the use of the static variable. There's many other ways you could do this. A simple way would be to use an `NSMutableDictionary` to map from filenames to `UIManagedDocument` instances. Something like this:

```
+ (UIManagedDocument *)sharedManagedDocumentForFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    //assuming we have an instance variable:  NSMutableDictionary *docDictionary
    UIManagedDocument *doc = [docDictionary objectForKey:fileName];

    if (!doc) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        // url is "<Documents Directory>/<vacationName>"

        doc = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

        [docDictionary setObject:doc forKey:fileName];
    }
    return doc;
}
```

**Update**

Because `sharedManagedDocumentForFile:` is a class method, you can't store `docDictionary` as an instance variable for your class, as you note. Instead, you can declare it in your `.m` file before your class implementation like so:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *docDictionary = nil;

@implementation MyClass ...
```

This in effect gives a single `docDictionary` instance that exists outside of any instances of your class. Instances of your classes can still access it though.

The `static` keyword ensures that this `docDictionary` variable can't be accessed outside the current compilation unit (i.e. source file). For more info on static and its many different meanings, see questions such as [Difference between static in C and static in C++??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943280/difference-between-static-in-c-and-static-in-c)

Comment: Occulus - thank you for the response.  What you suggested is a better solution for the reasons you explained with your example.  There is one thing I don't understand.  How can we access the instance variable docDictionary if the `sharedManagedDocumentForFile` is a class method?

Comment: Godo question. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you! .. I've implemented this and it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: Please fix addObject to setObject

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Use setObject, not addObject.