# Retaining a comboBox within a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a comboBox within a grid. Basically to get it I have to use findcontrol.

I am thinking of another option however. Within the init method I was planning on getting the value and storing it to a private static field:

```
private static RadComboBox theComboBox
```

Can someone please tell me if this is not good practice. ie. Is it unwise to be storing a relatively complex object like this in a static field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it.  See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563171/asp-net-c-static-variables-are-global) for answer why.  If you really want to do this, I'd use a session instead.